# Do I need RDF enabled on a normal site?

Tags: 7, rdf

When you install Drupal 7, you notice that RDF is enabled by default. Now... I have a website called [7 Tutorials](http://www.7tutorials.com) and I am wondering if RDF is useful, considering the content shared on the website.

I read a bit about it and learned that the "Resource Description Framework" is the standard for encoding metadata and other knowledge on the Semantic Web.

I admit I did not research much about it and I am not sure I fully understand its use cases but, it sounds to me RDF would be useful only to websites which share data in a structured way. Is this correct? Would I have anything to gain by enabling RDF on my website? (e.g. help with SEO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as Google is concerned if your website is well structured it will be easy for crawlers to crawl your website.Morever [Google Rich snippets](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-rich-snippets.html) uses RDF and it needs every site to be RDF structured if you want to enable rich snippets for your website.

[Drupal 7 rich snippets and RDF](http://openspring.net/blog/2011/09/30/schemaorg-rich-snippets-drupal-7-rdfa)

> So Unless you have any problem with RDF module enabled why you need to
>   disable it?

Comment: OK. So... If I enable this module, is there any additional maintenance work required?

Comment: No...you dont have to do any thing with this module.